# Android: cannot resolve appcompat-v7 themes

Tags: android, android-theme, android-appcompat

In `themes.xml`, I would like to change a theme from `Theme.Holo.Light.DarkActionBar` to `Theme.AppCompat.Light.DarkActionBar`

but I get:

> cannot resolve symbol
>   '@android:style/Theme.AppCompat.Light.DarkActionBar'

In the gradle file I added:

```
compile 'com.android.support:appcompat-v7:22.1.1'
```

I am using:

```
compileSdkVersion 22
buildToolsVersion "22.0.1"
```

I have also run gradle's `clean` command, but nothing seems to change.

Any ideas?

Comment: Try Tools > Android > Sync Project with Gradle Files and see if that helps.

Comment: Still not working :-(

Comment: The app compat themes are not part of the built-in styles. You have to reference them without the '@android:style' prefix. Just use something like: <style name="AppTheme" parent="Theme.AppCompat.Light.DarkActionBar">

Comment: @ebarrenechea YEAHH!!! that's exactly the reason it wasn't working!!! If you write an answer I can accept it as the solution

Answer (score 15, accepted):

The AppCompat themes are not part of the built-in styles. You have to reference them without the `'@android:style'` prefix.

Just use something like:

```
<style name="AppTheme" parent="Theme.AppCompat.Light.DarkActionBar">
```

Comment: I've been pulling my hair out over this. Finally someone has the answer. Thank you!

Comment: Seems like in my case Theme Editor was not working properly and it simply forgot to add that line into the actual styles.xml file... Thanks!