# Android Studio 3.0 cannot resolve symbol Theme

Tags: android, android-studio

As stated in style.xml, there is a weird error, which shows Cannot resolve symbol 'Theme', which is quite strange.

See pic of the error :- 
[image]

My Project Specs:-

Using Android Studio 3.0

and gradle version 3.0.0

and distributionUrl=https://services.gradle.org/distributions/gradle-4.1-all.zip

Edit:-

Tried clearing the cache by going to File > Invalidate Cache/Restart > Invalidate and Restart, but to no avail, as the error persists.

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/a/48734990/8311441 this saved me

Comment: I have tried by several ways, but not fixed. I think the gradle version and Android studio version should be matched.

Answer (score 20, accepted):

Another possible reason is: **Google's maven repository is not set** for the build script.

Open your project's main build.gradle add *this* line:

```
buildscript {
    repositories {
        google()  <-- this
        // Be also sure that google() is before jcenter()
    }
}
```

Without this, it may not be able to download the Android Studio Gradle plugin 3.0+. It's not distributed in jCenter but in the Google's maven repository.

Comment: Vote up, it's the only correct solution, at least in my case. This is weird, since it affects xml editor only, it compiles fine even without `google()` repository added.

Comment: Neither this, nor the other suggestions worked for me with plugin 3.1.x but fortunately I can still compile the project (despite the red letters that indicate an error).

Comment: Even running lint works fine despite the red letters. Must be an IDE bug.

Comment: @Gabor, the IDE problem is different and it's something newer. I've started seeing it after an upgrade few weeks ago. But the error from the OP is a real blocker. You can't build unless you fix it.

Comment: This doesnt help

Comment: Try this if above answer is not working : https://stackoverflow.com/a/43255281/3674079

Comment: Solution does not work for me. The Google Maven repo is already in my gradle.build file.

Answer (score 68):

Had the same issue after upgrading to Android Studio 3.1 (**EDIT**: bug still present at v3.1.3). What worked for me was clicking **File > Close Project** and then reopening the project from Studio's dialog.

[image: Android Studio's Entry Screen]

Comment: The is was the only thing that worked for me too, and i tried the other answers too (bug in 3.1 i believe).

Comment: Spent an hour doing all sorts of other weird stuff to try fixing this after 3.1, thank you!

Comment: Finally something that worked! (v3.1) - Must be a widely known bug?

Comment: Works for me too. Thanks

Comment: Worked for me after removing it from recent projects. (File, Open Recent, manage projects)

Comment: After all different kind of tries AS 3.1.1 still, continue with the above bug.

Comment: Similar approach but using "Import project (Gradle, Eclipse..)" did the trick for me. This seems to force all .idea files to be recreated from scratch.

Comment: This is zany -- the second Q&A I've consulted for this problem (studio v3.1.2), tried cleaning and rebuilding, syncing, disabling build cache, closing and reopening (*but from the sidebar list*), fiddling with gradle and appcompat versions and going through all of the above again -- to no avail.  Then this worked. >_>

Comment: It worked for me (Android 3.1.2). Neither Invalidate cache/restart nor Sync Project with Gradle files worked. It was sufficient to close the project and reopen it as described here. Now the error is gone.

Comment: It worked for me too (Android 3.1.2). Just like pierluca's answer, neither "Invalidate cache and restart", nor "Sync gradle" worked

Comment: This "Hello, IT. Have you tried closing it and opening again?"-solution saved my day. Thanks bro.

Comment: Thank you @cassioso for making me laugh so hard when I got the joke. Edited answer afterwards, to indicate that the bug (?) is still present at v3.2.1

Answer (score 8):

What worked for me was to click on **Gradle** to open the **Gradle projects** tool window and than on [refresh](https://i.stack.imgur.com/qYK7J.png). I think some depedencies where not loaded correctly.

Answer (score 6):

In my case, **Invalidate Caches/Restart** worked fine for me.

[image]

Answer (score 3):

*Goto* **File** -> **Invalidate Caches / Restart...** -> **Invalidate and Restart**

**Android Studio** will sort-of **close** and **delete all caches, indexes, etc**.. Then, **Android Studio** will **open** again. **Indexing** will be done and you're ready to proceed.

Comment: Can't believe that exists this feature. Tks!

Answer (score 2):

It seems to be a setting update of "injected references". Search this word in settings dialog and change its "Severity" option to a different value and apply, then change back to its original choice. The error highlight in the editor then disappears.

Comment: Thank you, can you explain what is "injected references"? BTW updated to beta 5 and issue got resolved :)

Comment: I was not quite sure and just met the same problem as you.  I clicked the bulb icon by moving cursor to the error highlight and it gave some hints about the problem.

Comment: Click on File -> Invalidate and Restart -> Invalidate and Restart to fix the problem

Answer (score 1):

> **Solution 1:**
>
> 1. GOTO > 'build.gradle(Module:app)',
> 2. ADD > "buildToolsVersion '28.0.2'" as following :
>
> ```
> android {
>     signingConfigs {}
>     compileSdkVersion 28
>     defaultConfig
>     {
>         applicationId "com.example.project"
>         minSdkVersion 21
>         targetSdkVersion 28
>         versionCode 1
>         versionName "1.0"
>         testInstrumentationRunner "android.support.test.runner.AndroidJUnitRunner"
>     }
>     buildTypes
>     {
>         release
>         {
>             minifyEnabled false
>             proguardFiles getDefaultProguardFile('proguard-android.txt'), 'proguard-rules.pro'
>         }
>     }
>
>     buildToolsVersion '28.0.1'
> }
> ```
>
> 3. Click on 'Sync Now', and it's done.
> 4. GOTO > 'File' > 'Invalidate Cache/Restart'.
> 5. Done.
>
> **If That doesn't work, following might help (Solution 2) :**
>
> 1. GOTO > 'SDK Manager' > 'SDK Tools' > Click on 'Show Package Details',
> 2. Check if there is a NEW Version of 'SDK Build-Tools' Available,
> 3. Then Download it and Change to newer version "buildToolsVersion '28.0.x'" in 'build.gradle (Module:app)',
> 4. Sync again.
> 5. GOTO > 'File' > 'Invalidate Cache/Restart'.
> 6. Done.
>
> **If That doesn't work, following might help (Solution 3) :**
>
> 1. Remove/Cut following dependencies :
>
>    ```
>    implementation 'com.android.support:appcompat-v7:x.x.x'
>    implementation 'com.android.support:design:x.x.x'
>    ```
> 2. Click on 'Sync Now',
> 3. Add/Paste dependencies again and Sync again.
> 4. Done.
>
> **NOTE : You can do Solution 1 then 2 then 3 for better results.**
>
> Hope it helped :)

Answer (score 0):

Close the project and import it again. Worked for me today.

Answer (score 0):

#### Simplest Solution

- Close project
- Import/Reopen project again (Open from directory)

Answer (score -2):

Delete `'com.android.support:appcompat-v7:27.0.0','com.android.support:design:27.0.0'` compile from app build.gradle then sync and then again paste those 2 compile then sync.... it will solve