# Cannot resolve symbol 'Theme' in Android Studio despite syncing project

Tags: xml, android-studio, android-theme

My project builds and runs smoothly however in styles.xml the "Theme" is highlighted in red and this error is brought to my notice each time I commit my project to Git:

`Error:(4, 36) Cannot resolve symbol 'Theme'`

styles.xml:

```
<resources>

<!-- Base application theme. -->
<style name="AppTheme" parent="Theme.AppCompat.Light.DarkActionBar">
    <!-- Customize your theme here. -->
    <item name="colorPrimary">@color/colorPrimary</item>
    <item name="colorPrimaryDark">@color/colorPrimaryDark</item>
    <item name="colorAccent">@color/colorAccent</item>
</style>
```

Note that I have tried syncing my project with gradle files and have ensured that `google()` is present in my buildscript block in `build.gradle` as mentioned in the answers to these questions:

1] [Android Studio 3.0 cannot resolve symbol Theme](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/46053418/android-studio-3-0-cannot-resolve-symbol-theme/46887832)

2] [Cannot resolve symbol 'Theme' in styles.xml (Android Studio)](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/40822173/cannot-resolve-symbol-theme-in-styles-xml-android-studio)

The accepted/top voted answers in these questions did not solve my problem, please help

Answer (score 6, accepted):

To fix this problem delete these libraries from **build.gradle**

> com.android.support:appcompat-v7:27.1.1
>
> com.android.support:design:27.1.1

sync and undo delete and sync again

Comment: Is this safe? because I'm unable to build my project after removing `com.android.support:appcompat-v7:27.1.1` getting an error : `AAPT2 error: check logs for details`

Comment: please re-add those dependencies again from **build-Edit libraries and Dependencies**  which are latest versions and resync the project

Comment: I see you had edited your answer adding the phrase "undo delete", which I didn't see. This solved solved my problem, thank you!