# Android Studio: Unresolved symbol "Theme" in styles.xml

Tags: android, android-studio, android-studio-3.0

I am having trouble with Android Studio throwing an error in my styles.xml about unresolved symbol "Theme".  The error is throw where I have my AppBaseTheme defined as below.

```
<style name="AppBaseTheme" parent="Theme.AppCompat.NoActionBar">
```

This only started after I upgrade from com.android.tools.build:gradle:3.1.3 to 3.1.4.  If I revert back to 3.1.3, it works but it then complains and says i should upgrade to 3.1.4.

This one works...

> classpath 'com.android.tools.build:gradle:3.1.3'

This one does NOT work

> classpath 'com.android.tools.build:gradle:3.1.4'

What should I do?  I've tried restarting, doing an Invalidate Cache and Restart, etc.  Nothing seems to work.

Comment: have you tried to change gradle-wrapper.properties file in gradle

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Did you try to update the `compileSDK` Version? According to this post the reason can be both in the [compileSDK](https://stackoverflow.com/a/49523920/4721831) or that the library is out of [sync](https://stackoverflow.com/a/51324829/4721831), or even you have to cancel .idea, or the google [repository](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/46053418/android-studio-3-0-cannot-resolve-symbol-theme) that is not set.

Comment: brilliant!  I didn't even think to upgrade the compileSDK as it did not mention it was affected.  I upgraded from compileSDK 26 to 27 and also the necessary dependencies to 27.1.1 and it's working now.  Thank you!!!