# cannot resolve symbol '?selectableItemBackgroundBorderless'

Tags: android, xml, android-layout, user-interface

I'm facing a strange issue. When I use following attributes that perfectly working and I can see the ripple effect in the device.

```
android:foreground="?selectableItemBackgroundBorderless"

android:background="?selectableItemBackgroundBorderless"
```

But in **IDE** It shows an error cannot resolve symbol `'?selectableItemBackgroundBorderless'`.

Android Studio: v3.1.2

```
compileSdkVersion 27
buildToolsVersion "27.0.3"

support_version = '27.1.1'
```

what could be the issue?

Comment: android:background="?attr/selectableItemBackground"

Comment: Do you have maven { url 'https://maven.google.com' } in your gradle?

Comment: android:background="?attr/selectableItemBackground" also same

Comment: @ZezariyaNilesh is better : android:foreground="?android:attr/selectableItemBackground"

Comment: yeah I have google() in my repositories @Skizo-ozᴉʞS

Comment: forground also same error @Skizo-ozᴉʞS

Comment: @BhuvaneshBS may be isuue with `27.0.3` try to use `27.0.2` it will work

Comment: stackoverflow.com/a/48734990/4385913 visit

Comment: android:background="?android:attr/selectableItemBackgroundBorderless" and remove error use tools:ignore="NewApi".

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I have faced same issue with **`27.0.3`**

With **`27.0.3`** version

[image]

With **`27.0.2`** version

[image]

Use **`27.0.2`** instead of  **`27.0.3`**

Than

**`Clean-ReBuild-Run`** You project

**EDIT**

if you want to use **`27.0.3`** than follow this answer https://stackoverflow.com/a/48734990/7666442

Answer (score 0):

**From API version Level 21 onwards use:**

```
android:foreground="?android:attr/selectableItemBackgroundBorderless"
android:background="?android:attr/selectableItemBackgroundBorderless"
```

Comment: Add some description