# Android Studio Project Doesn't recognize Base Theme Base.Theme

Tags: android, themes, radix

For some reason, and I can't seem to find the answer to this anywhere or even why, my one of my Android Studio Projects is just absolutely confused as all about the base theme. Why??? How is this fixed? My other projects seem fine and have no problem with it. [image]

Edit: This seems to have done the trick:  [Android Cannot resolve symbol '?attr/selectableItemBackground'](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/44007653/android-cannot-resolve-symbol-attr-selectableitembackground/48734990#48734990)

Answer (score 0):

I am answering this too late, however this might help someone who is facing this issue. Here is what I did.

1. Go to `.idea/libraries/` folder of your project
2. Locate the `Gradle__com_android_support_.....xml` files
3. Delete all of them which you have located.
4. Now go back to Android Studio and click `File` > `Sync IDE with file system`
5. Next `File` > `Sync project with Gradle files`
6. Finally Rebuild your project

Hope this helps.